# SSH between two subnets

Tags: networking, routing

This is my setup:

[image: My Network]

1. Custom Built Pfsense box `192.168.0.1`, DHCP Server Range `192.168.0.3-150` (A)

   2. Netgear WNR3500L running Tomato firmware `192.168.1.1` DHCP range `192.168.1.2-50` it is connected as an open-vpn client. WAN IP is set to `192.168.0.1` but changes after connecting to VPN. (B)
   3. ASUS RT-AC66u connected to router A as AP `192.168.0.2`
   4. Custom built NAS running synology DSM, 3 ethernet ports. connected to both routers two IP's `192.168.0.10` from 1 and `192.168.1.10` from 2
   5. Banani Pi Pro running transmission `192.168.1.5` downloading to network share on `192.168.1.10` internet traffic is pushed through VPN.
   6. Banani Pi Pro running Pivpn server `192.168.0.15` for remote access to my network.
   7. Several client machines with the IP range `192.168.0.XX`

What I want to do?

I want to access my transmission webpage on `192.168.1.5:9091` and also SSH to it while only connected to the 1st network with `192.168.0.XX`

At the moment when I am at home on my primary workstation I am able to achieve this by doing the following, direct connection to Router A through ethernet port + Wifi connection to Router B.

I want to remotely connect to my vpn server on `192.168.0.15` and SSH into `192.168.1.5`

Is this possible without losing any of my networks intended functionality?

I only want torrent traffic to be pushed through the VPN on router B.

Also is there a more efficient way of doing things? My pfsense box is capable of running as a VPN server so I might get rid of #6. It is also able to simultaneously connect as a VPN client but I'm confused as to how only the torrent traffic would be pushed through it. If there is a way to get rid of a few of the devices in my setup suggestions will be seriously considered I've got too much clutter in my garage.

Comment: Could you provide a network diagram?  It's hard to visualize all of that text.

Comment: @Hydraxan14 Just did :)

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.1.5 from 192.168.0.8?

Comment: I cant but I can ping it from 192.168.1.8 which is the same computer just a different interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to ping Transmission (192.168.1.5) from Primary Workstation (192.168.0.8).

### Routes

- Primary Workstation should route 192.168.1.0/24 traffic to the interface that Router A is on.
- Router A should route 192.168.1.0/24 traffic to the interface that
  Router B is on.
- Router B should route 192.168.0.0/24 traffic to the interface that
  Router A is on.

### Firewalls

- No blocking `icmp` messages on Router A, Router B, Transmission, or Primary Workstation.

---

As for connecting to Transmission via VPN:

- VPN Client should route 192.168.1.0/24 traffic to the VPN interface.